# Using AsyncStorage + React Native to Reload RSS Feed Content Faster after inital Load

Tags: performance, asynchronous, rss, react-native

I am very new to AsyncStorage's usage and I want to be sure that I am employing it in my code in the right way. I am trying to speed up various loading processes within my app, which essentially is a media app that takes various rss feeds, filters through them based on the user's interests, and creates a customized feed of content.

The first time around, I use fetch on an array of promises from selected rss feeds and then return the data inside custom components. The items within the returned array of articles is randomized (to not seem static), but I only want to load and randomize the array of articles once.

Here's the code loading the rss feeds in custom components:

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
    View, 
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    Text, 
    ListView, 
    TouchableHighlight, 
    AsyncStorage, 
} = React;

//additional libraries
var Parse = require('parse/react-native');
//var Reflux = require('reflux');

//dynamic component references
var ArticlePreview = require('./exp_base_components/article-preview');
var Api = require('../utils/api');
var FeedStore = require('../stores/feed-store');
var ArticleDetails = require('./exp_base_components/article-details');
var Spinner = require('react-native-spinkit');
//var Actions = require('../../actions');

//dimensions
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var window = Dimensions.get('window');

module.exports = React.createClass({ 
    componentWillMount: function() {
        Parse.User.currentAsync()
            .then((user) => { this.setState({user: user}); })
    },  
    componentDidMount: function() {
        //console.log(this.state.user);
        var personalFeed = null; 
        var Onboarding = Parse.Object.extend("Onboarding");
        var query = new Parse.Query(Onboarding);
        query.equalTo("userObjectId", Parse.User.current());
        var that = this;
        query.find({
          success: function(result) {
            console.log("Successfully retrieved " + result.length + " users!");
            var object = result[0];
            console.log(object.id);
            // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
            console.log(object.get('interests'));
            that.fetchData(object.get('interests'));
          },
          error: function(error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
          }
        });

    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            user: null, 
            personalFeed: null, 
            isLoaded: false, 
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
               rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
            }), 
        }
    },
    fetchData: function(personalFeed) {
        var that = this; 
        FeedStore.getArticles(personalFeed)
            .then((data) => {
                var entries = data; 
                that.setState({
                    dataSource : that.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(entries),
                    isLoaded   : true, 
                });
            }).done();
    }, 
    render: function() {

        if (!this.state.isLoaded) {
            return this.renderLoadingView();
        }
        return this.renderListView();
    }, 
    renderLoadingView: function() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Spinner style={styles.spinner} isVisible={!this.state.isLoaded} size={50} type={'Arc'} color={'#FF0000'}/>
            </View>
        );
    }, 
    renderListView: function() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ListView
                    dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
                    initialListSize = {5}
                    pageSize={5}
                    renderRow  = {this.renderEntry} />
            </View>
        );
    }, 
    renderEntry: function(entry) {

        if (typeof entry.mediaGroups === 'undefined')
        {
            return (
                <ArticlePreview
                    category={entry.categories[0]}
                    key={entry.title}
                    heartText={'2.9k'}
                    categoryPress={this.onCategoryDetailsPress}
                    selected={false}
                    source={require('../img/stock_image.png')}
                    text={entry.title.toLowerCase().replace('&nbsp;','')}
                    onPress={() => this.onArticleDetailsPress(entry)} />
            );
        } else 
        { 
            var url = entry.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].url; 
            if (url.indexOf('w=150') > -1)
            {
                url.replace("w=150", "w=500");
            }
            var catsource = entry.categories[0]; 
            if (typeof catsource == "undefined")
            {
                catsource = "News";
            }
            return (
                <ArticlePreview
                    category={catsource}
                    key={entry.title}
                    heartText={'2.9k'}
                    categoryPress={this.onCategoryDetailsPress}
                    selected={false}
                    source={{uri: url }}
                    text={entry.title.toLowerCase().replace('&nbsp;','')}
                    onPress={() => this.onArticleDetailsPress(entry)} />
            );
        }

    },
    onCategoryDetailsPress: function() {
        //forward to sytled web view of categorical article feed
        console.log("onCategoryDetailsPress"); 
    }, 
    onArticleDetailsPress: function(entry) {
        //forward to sytled web view of article details given link
        console.log("onArticleDetailsPress"); 
        console.log(entry);

        this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([{
            name: 'articledetails',
            passProps: {entry: entry},
        }]);
    }, 
    /*
    onChange: function(event, articles) {
        this.setState({articles: articles}); //trigers re-render of component
    }
    */

});


styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1, 
        alignItems: 'center', 
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#000000', 
    }, 
    activityIndicator: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    spinner: {
        marginBottom: 50,
    },
});
```

Here's the loading sequence:

[image]

Is there a way to incorporate AsyncStorage in this process so that when the user visits the frame again (for the 2nd+ time) the data can load faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the data in AsyncStorage like this:

```
  const STORAGE_KEY = 'yourkey';

  fetchData: function(personalFeed) {
        var that = this; 
        FeedStore.getArticles(personalFeed)
            .then((data) => {
                var entries = data; 
                // Set a key for AsyncStorage, and Stringify the data
                AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(data))
                that.setState({
                    dataSource : that.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(entries),
                    isLoaded   : true, 
                });
            }).done();
  }
```

Then retrieve it like this:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY)
  .then((storedData) => {
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(storedData)  
    // do something with the parsedData
  })
  .catch((err) => {
     // Could set the AnsyncStorage key here since it was not found.
  })
```

Comment: Would i conditionally check if the item is available with the data before calling fetch?

Comment: You could do a .catch to do your fetch if the item is not in storage ( updated answer to show this )